# Error while creating BranchType in Clearcase 7.1.2 using CM API through Web View

Tags: java, clearcase

I am getting error while creating BranchType in Clearcase 7.1.2 using CM API through Web View

Following is my method for creating BranchType :

```
static void createBranchType(String branchTypeName, CcProvider provider, String repositoryName) throws WvcmException
{       
    CcBranchType newBr = provider.ccBranchType(provider.userFriendlySelector(Domain.CLEAR_CASE, Namespace.BRTYPE, branchTypeName, repositoryName));
    newBr.doCreateCcBranchType(null, null);
}
```

After running this code I am getting following exception :

> CRVAP0236E (not-allowed):  Unable to perform operation makeCcResource (CcBranchType.doCreateCcBranchType) on 'cc.brtype:NewBRJava': operation not allowed.
>         ...com.ibm.rational.stp.ws.schema.ErrorFault: 
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod$WsException.stpException(DctMethod.java:2398)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod.handleErrorFault(DctMethod.java:1763)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod.invoke(DctMethod.java:1114)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod.invoke(DctMethod.java:848)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod.invoke(DctMethod.java:1241)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.ccrc.CcMkResource.run(CcMkResource.java:67)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.CoreResource.runProtocolOp(CoreResource.java:800)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.core.CoreResource.runOp(CoreResource.java:746)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcResourceImpl.runCcMkResourceOpInternal(CcResourceImpl.java:669)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcResourceImpl.runCcMkResourceOp(CcResourceImpl.java:630)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcBranchTypeImpl.doCreateCcBranchType(CcBranchTypeImpl.java:52)
>           at Example.createBranchType(Example.java:327)
>           at Example.main(Example.java:271)
>       Caused by: CRVSV0130E No object could be found that allows the requested operation.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.(BeanDeserializer.java:120)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.(BeanDeserializer.java:106)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.ws.schema.ErrorFault.getDeserializer(ErrorFault.java:345)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerAs(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:464)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForType(DeserializationContext.java:547)
>           at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.java:157)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>           at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
>           at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:424)
>           at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2765)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2748)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2424)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2347)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1804)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.ws.teamservice.TeamBindingStub.makeCcResource(TeamBindingStub.java:2956)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.wsutil.DctMethod.invoke(DctMethod.java:1020)
>           ... 10 more

I am stuck with this error from lat 5 days. I searched a lot on IBM forum and on google also but still no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By some wild chance is the name you pass in "cc.brtype:NewBRJava"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally. The error was because of incorrect repository tag. I was passing the repository name but it requires the repository tag name (VOB tag) in method userFriendlySelector(Domain.CLEAR_CASE, Namespace.BRTYPE, branchTypeName, **repositoryName**). This should be VOB tag.